# how to manage Student and Book issuing relation in Library Management System in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In Library Management System, how to keep transaction done by student in taking book....I have got two table Student and Book which have one to many relationship...Now if any student is issuing 5 different book then how this information is stored in Database?? please help

Comment: I gave upvote to Steve, but I really don't know for sure what you're asking, based on your tags and question.

Comment: Please paste the SQL you have tested to count the number of books checked out by each student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Student can borrow zero or more Books, a Book is borrowed by zero or more Students. This is a textbook *many to many* relationship and it requires a third table

So you need a Borrows table with a structure like this

```
Create Table Borrows
( 
  IDBook int not null, 
  IDStudent int not null,
  BorrowDate smalldatetime not null,
  ReturnDate smalldatetime null,
  BookStatusBefore nvarchar(32) not null, 
  BookStatusAfter nvarchar(32) not null
)

-- Primary key on IDBook+IDStudent....
ALTER TABLE Borrows ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Borrows PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
IDBook,
IDStudent
)
```

Now you can register a Borrow event and keep track of the whereabout of a book and other historical information about the event itself.

Comment: by use of Borrows table, do we manually need to add data in IDBook and IDStudent Column or will it get automatically filled by Relationship?? Plz help..i am begineer and dont know much about table relationship

Comment: No. The relationship cannot find by itself what user and what book has been borrowed. Usually, in your user interface you let the operatore choose the book and the student. (and this gives you the BookID and StudentID or whatever you use as primary keys for these tables) then it is just simple INSERT INTO